# Sort files by mp3-id3-tag

Tags: c#, mp3

I got the nuget package ID3.NET from nuget. I would like to sort the mp3 files by their artist. But I don't really know, what is the right way, to use the files with the mp3 info.

```
DirectoryInfo rootDir = rootDir.GetFiles("*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo dir in fileList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", dir);

    using (var mp3 = new Mp3File(dir.FullName))
    {
       Id3Tag tag = mp3.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag);
       Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", tag.Title.Value);
       Console.WriteLine("Artist: {0}", tag.Artists.Value);
       Console.WriteLine("Album: {0}", tag.Album.Value);
    }
}
```

To sort the file by e.g. their size, I use this working code.

```
fileList = rootDir.GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                  .Where(s => Worker.sExtensionFilerStrings
                  .Contains(Path.GetExtension(s.ToString()).ToLower()))
                  .OrderBy(jo => jo.Name);
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error? Be specific please!

Comment: TagLib Sharp is a nice .NET library you can use to read IDv2 tags. Ive tried it with mp3 and flac files. As to sorting a list, thats a different concern, but im sure you can use google..

Comment: I don't know how to sort by the given mp3 tags.

Comment: The example of sorting by filesize is a monster call of three lines of code in one statement. This is bad coding style imo and you should try do break things into smaller parts. Then you will have less trouble to adapt it to other requirements. - Create/fill  a List of a  tag data structure or class and sort it.. - One-liners are bad for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your example expanded minimally to allow sorting by a Tag:

```
string[] musicFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mp3test", "*.mp3");


// a structure to hold the filename and the tags object:
public struct mp3FileTags
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public Id3Tag tags { get; set; }
    public mp3FileTags(string fn, Id3Tag t) 
    { this = new mp3FileTags(); fileName = fn; tags = t; }
}

// we create a list of the mp3FileTags objects:
List<mp3FileTags> mp3s = new List<mp3FileTags>();

foreach (string musicFile in musicFiles)
{
    using (var mp3 = new Mp3File(musicFile))
    {
        Id3Tag tag = mp3.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.FileStartTag);
        mp3s.Add(new mp3FileTags(musicFile, tag));          // fill the list
    }
}

// now we can order it:
mp3s = mp3s.OrderBy(o => o.tags.Artists.ToString()).ToList();

// now we can use the ordered list:
foreach (mp3FileTags FTag in mp3s)
{
    Id3Tag tag = FTag.tags;
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", FTag.fileName);
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", tag.Title.Value.);
    Console.WriteLine("Artist: {0}", tag.Artists.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Album: {0}", tag.Album.Value);
}
```

You may note how I avoid using arrays for List

BTW: I'm not convinced whether I'd be going with ID3.Lib; it seems to be undocumented and abandoned..

**Update** I have replaced the direct `Id3Tag` in the List by a structure, that contains the filename and the tags. You could include more data there e.g. a FileInfo object..

Comment: Thank you, the structure helps me a lot